# Can't send email from AWS

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

my application is on aws EC2 it was sending email very well suddenly it started throwing exception

```
javax.mail.MessagingException'.
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:826)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:761)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:685)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.server.utils.EmailServicesImpl.sendMail(EmailServicesImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my email settings

```
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtp.host=smtp.mydomain.in
mail.smtp.port = 587
```

i tried with `port 25` also but the problem is still same.

Answer (score 2):

According to your setting, you require StartTLS. The default port for that is 587 which is fine; changing it to 25 will most definitely break it.

And your error message states `authentication failed`, so I'd suspect that you are either not providing credentials or the wrong ones.

Comment: i had fill up the form https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request one day before in this form i entered my instance EIB,AWS Account Number*,my email and use case but didn't give Reverse DNS Record for EIP 1. Is it necessary to give Reverse DNS Record for EIP 1  ?

Comment: yes, you can get reverse DNS lookups, but only for elastic IPs and you need to ask support for that change. if you need it will depend on your smtp provider. have you considered amazon's SES or mandrillapp for sending mails? might be easier